# Building an external kernel module with Yocto Honister and devtool: ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid

Tags: yocto, kernel-module

When building an external kernel module with devtool build in Yocto, the build sometimes fails.

```
|   ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
|          include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
|          Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug but there is a workaround. Just execute

```
bitbake -c cleansstate make-mod-scripts
```